# IIS6 Integrated Authentication fails when logging in from server, but not from client

Tags: iis-6, windows-authentication

I have an II6 server, where a website is configured for "Integrated Authentication".

When I access the website from any client within the company, it prompts for username and password, and if I set those, the site seems to load just fine.

If I access the website from the server itself, it prompts me, but even if I use the same credentials as from a client, it just gives a 401 http error.

Does anyone have any clue what is going on here? Why isn't it working from the server itself?
Why is it prompting for username/password from the internal clients?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today and this seems to solve it:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

I used method 1 and the hostnames need to be in this format: `intranet1.site.com` where `intranet1` is the server name, and `site` is the IIS site name (you'll need to have a line for each IIS site).